# add PID controller to odeint integration

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration, odeint, pid-controller

I have an integral to which I want to control the input by adding a P-controller to.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

xs = []
yd = []

def dY(y, x):
    a = 0.001
    yin = 1
    C = 0.01
    N = 1
    dC = C/N
    b1 = 0
    y_diff = -np.copy(y)
    y_diff[0] += yin
    y_diff[1:] += y[:-1]
    xs.append(x)
    yd.append(y_diff)
    return (a/dC)*y_diff+b1*dC

x = np.linspace(0,20,1000)
y0 = np.zeros(4)
res = odeint(dY, y0, x)

plt.plot(x,res, '-')

plt.gca().set_prop_cycle(plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'])
plt.plot(np.array(xs),np.array(yd), '-.')

plt.show()
```

y_in is a variable that I want to control by a P/PI-controller in order to reach a certain setpoint. I have looked at it in different ways but I honestly have no idea where to start with implementing the controller.

I am familiar with the concept of PID controller and all related equations however this is a total new thing for me to implement in a case where ODEINT is used.

Hopefully someone could help me out.

Comment: *"I am familiar with the concept of PID controller and all related equations ..."*  So when you add a controller to your system, you end up with a bigger system of differential equations.  To use `odeint`, you'll have to write the entire system (i.e. "plant" plus controller) as one system of differential equations.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser and how do I get my current code to the one system of differential equations because honestly the implementation of such is a total blur for me.